# Summing and grouping by multiple indexes pandas

Tags: pandas, sum, grouping

I have a data frame with years as indexes:

```
index  deaths_pop

2010      2
2011      6
2012      2
2013      8
2014      10
2015      4
2016      2
```

I want to group and sum by index as follows:

```
index    deaths_pop

=<2012     10
>2012      24
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `groupby` on `pd.cut`

```
(df.groupby(pd.cut(df.index, [0, 2012, np.inf], labels=['=<2012', '>2012']))
   .deaths_pop.sum())

Out[849]:
=<2012    10
>2012     24
Name: deaths_pop, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Just tried and it's summingt the indexes "=<2012" == 3 (they are 2010, 2011, 2012) and  ">2012"==4 (they are 2013, 2015, 2015 and 2016)

Comment: I was trying with this code: 

df.groupby(np.where(df.index > 2012, '>2012', s.index)).sum() and it worked, but i also need to sum those years before 2012 (including 2012). How can I do that?

Comment: I tested it on your sample data. It works correctly.  `"=<2012"` summing on 3 rows `2010, 2011, 2012` is wrong? on your second comment, what is `s.index` ?

Comment: Ops, it's "df.index"... Edit:I tested again and it worked. My fault! Thank you.

Comment: if you need to split into 2 buckets only : `'>2012'` and `'=<2012'`. Your command need to change to `df.groupby(np.where(df.index > 2012, '>2012', '=<2012')).sum()`.  My command generalizes to n-buckets.

Comment: What if I need to sum not only deaths_pop, but another column?

Comment: if sum all columns, just take out `.death_pop` as in : `df.groupby(pd.cut(df.index, [0, 2012, np.inf], labels=['=<2012', '>2012'])).sum()`